# error:missing package statement 'src' but still can run the code in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm new to Java, I created a repo in Gitlab and imported to IntelliJ, it's a new repo so nothing in the folder now. I created a folder 'src' manually on my machine and created a java file.

```
public class Test{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println("This is a test!");
  }

}
```

The code works fine, but the first line under 'Test' there's a curvy red line, normally if I create a new project in IntelliJ, I won't have this kind of problem, is it because I can't create 'src' folder manually? How can I fix this?
[image]

Comment: by adding a package statement.

Comment: @Stultuske the red line disappeared but the file name is still red, normally a java class is shown as white color

Comment: You probably messed up your project definition. It seems that IntelliJ assumes that your class lives inside a package that should be named **src**.

Comment: @GhostCatsaysReinstateMonica yeah I guess so, how can I fix this?

Comment: That is really hard to say without knowing what exactly you did there. Honestly: I would step back, read some intellij help/tutorial (I am sure that there are plenty step by step introductions), and then start anew.

Comment: Yeah this is a good idea, I'll just start all over again, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to mark the folder src you created as source in: 
     File->project structure->Modules

Comment: I've tried this already, can I delete this one and created a new project, but the problem would be how can I link this new project to my new repo?

Answer (score 0):

To add package statement, add this on the top of java file:

```
package foldername;
```